# Problem with keosd

Tags: cleos, nodeos, keosd

I have installed EOSIO from https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v1.4.3

`cleos` is working properly. But there is something wrong with `keosd`

```
cybrosys@cybrosys:~$ cleos wallet create
"/usr/opt/eosio/1.4.3/bin/keosd" launched
Unable to connect to keosd, if keosd is running please kill the process and try again.


cybrosys@cybrosys:~$ keosd
info  2018-11-09T09:58:29.003 thread-0  wallet_plugin.cpp:42          plugin_initialize    ] initializing wallet plugin
warn  2018-11-09T09:58:29.003 thread-0  wallet_plugin.cpp:68          plugin_initialize    ] 3120000 wallet_exception: Wallet exception
Failed to open wallet lock file at /home/cybrosys/eosio-wallet/./wallet.lock
    {"f":"/home/cybrosys/eosio-wallet/./wallet.lock"}
    thread-0  wallet_manager.cpp:284 initialize_lock
Failed to initialize
```

I have done `pkill keosd`. But still `keosd` is not running

Comment: Have you set the wallet-url somewhere in the config file?

Comment: Same problem here... not sure how to make keosd work correctly. https://eosforum.org/t/can-get-keosd-run-correctly/1944

Comment: please check the answer @fernandojimenez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it.

What I found is, keosd is running somehow in the system. Find it and kill it. Try the commands below

- Find PID of the running keosd process

  ps -ef | grep keosd
- Kill it

  kill -9 pid

  //replace 'pid' with value returned by the first command
- Run keosd in a specified port(8900)

  keosd --http-server-address=127.0.0.1:8900

Also, make sure that you have `eosio-wallet` directory and related files in your home directory

Answer (score 0):

Just simplifying answer by @Muhzin, pkill should do the job:

```
pkill keosd
```